# Apart from the need to inject 'test' and 'fixture' as globals, does TestCafe really need to compile test code itself?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

Just curious from a technical perspective: what is TestCafe doing in the compilation step apart from injecting the `test` and `fixture` functionality into the module? How much re-architecting would need to be done to allow the user to pass in tests as real live code, instead of needing there to be a text file of it that TestCafe will pick up and compile. For example:

```js
testcafe
  .createRunner()
  .fixtures([{
    name: "log in",
    beforeEach: setUp,
    tests: [{
      name: "happy path",
      async body(t){
        await t.navigateTo() // ...
      }   
    }]
  }])
```

I ask this because it's something we've run into at work a handful of times, where we'd like to be able to do things a particular way (run tests according to very specific logic, modify tests at runtime, etc), but this requirement of TestCafe's makes it messier than it might be if you could simply pass in tests as javascript objects.

Comment: Please clarify what 'specific logic' are you talking about and why the standard 'filter' and 'metadata' approaches do not meet your requirements. Also, how do you want to modify tests at runtime and why? Perhaps, there's an existing solution that might help you, or your clarification can help the team to understand your requirements.